# How to cast an anonymous class in PHP 7.x?

Tags: php, types

I wondered if there was a way to type the return of a method that instantiates an anonymous class?

php

```
public function getApi() // <-- type ?
{
    $api = $this->api ?: [];
    return new class ($api)
    {
        private $key, $validTill;
        public function __construct(array $api)
        {
            $this->key       = array_key_exists('key', $api) ? $api['key'] : null;
            $this->validTill = array_key_exists('validTill', $api) ? $api['validTill'] : null;
        }
        public function getKey():?string
        {
            return $this->key;
        }
        public function getValidTill(): ?string
        {
            return $this->validTill;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this can't be a concrete class defined elsewhere?

Comment: create an interface for that class, implement that interface and use it as type hint?

Comment: yes, it is mainly used in the symfony dependency injector in this form: [@service=(handle_api).getApi().getKey()] , you know ?

Comment: nope it's not instance of stdClass if I dump the type of this I've class@anonymous

Comment: `public function getApi():object` is an option.

Comment: ^ d̶e̶p̶e̶n̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶*̶w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶*̶ ̶P̶H̶P̶ ̶7̶ ̶v̶e̶r̶s̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶d
 ... scratch that,  it was the `?` nullable prefix that was introduced in 7.1

Comment: @blues Indeed, it seems to be that. It's weird I've had mistakes.  0ô http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9335b3ef0a8c58fba8765ded2cfa1cc99f1c0f05

Comment: Return types need a named type. Anonymous classes are... well anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about the type, or behavior, of the returned class, you really should define an interface for this:

```
interface KeyInterface 
{
    public function getKey(): ?string;
    public function getValidTill(): ?string;
}
```

Then have the anonymous class implement the interface:

```
public function getApi(): KeyInterface
{
    $api = $this->api ?: [];
    return new class ($api) implements KeyInterface
    ...
}
```

Anonymous classes can still implement interfaces and inherit from other classes.